# Swift Delegate Not Being Called

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a view with a delegate that I want to have call numpadView(numpadView:) in GameController upon button press, however I can't get it to work.  The overload of touchesBegan() works fine, it's really the line with pressDelegate?.numpadView(self) which doesn't call the delegate function in the GameController class.  I'm stumped as to what's missing to get it to work?

I cleaned the code to leave only the essential related to the problem for simplicity.

**NumpadView.swift**

```
protocol NumpadPressDelegateProtocol {
  func numpadView(numpadView: NumpadView)
}

class NumpadView: UIButton{
  var pressDelegate: NumpadPressDelegateProtocol?

  init(char: Character) {
    let frame = CGRectMake(160, 100, 50, 50)
    super.init(frame:frame)

    self.setTitle("\(char)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.userInteractionEnabled = true
  }

  override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    pressDelegate?.numpadView(self)
  } 
}
```

**GameController.swift**

```
class GameController: NumpadPressDelegateProtocol {

  func numpadView(numpadView: NumpadView) {
    //do something
  }

}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Declaring `GameController` as `NumpadPressDelegateProtocol` is not enough for you to get a callback. You also need to set the `pressDelegate` of the  `NumpadView` instance inside the  `Gamecontroller`. Assuming `numpadView` is the instance variable be it IBOutlet or not, you have to set the delegate like

Inside GameController init

```
 numpadView.pressDelegate = self
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the `pressDelegate` property to something? Nothing is assigned to it in the code you've shown. Do you assign something to it elsewhere in your code?

Comment: No, I don't.  What should I assign to it and where?

Comment: You need to create a `GameController` object and assign that to your `pressDelegate` property. Since `GameController` is declared to conform to your `NumpadPressDelegateProtocol` protocol. Then, when your `touchesBegan` function executes, there will be a `pressDelegate` object for it to call `numpadView()` on.