# Delegates with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

Currently I have a ViewController with a TableView and a custom Header containing a back button. What I want is to say from the header class that the ViewController has to go back to the previous ViewController. The problem I'm facing is that I'm conforming the protocol and the action of the button is received but the debugger doesn't go to the dismiss function. Here's the code:

```
    protocol StoresFilterHeaderViewDelegate: class {
        func onBackButtonTap();
    }
    class StoresFilterHeaderView: UICollectionReusableView {

        weak var delegate: StoresFilterHeaderViewDelegate?;
        @IBOutlet weak var lbSubcategory: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var ivSubcategory: UIImageView!

        // MARK: Actions

          @IBAction func onBackToMomentDetailButtonTap(_ sender: AnyObject) {
                self.delegate?.onBackButtonTap();
                print("button pressed");
      }
    }
```

> *"button pressed" is printed well*

---

```
class StoresFilterViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, StoresFilterHeaderViewDelegate {

    func onBackButtonTap() {
        print("segueback")
    }
```

> "segueback" is not being printed

Comment: Did you set the delegate of `StoresFilterHeaderView`? (`<instance of the custom view>.delegate = self`)

Comment: @the4kman I set: `weak var delegate: StoresFilterHeaderViewDelegate?;` is not that?

Comment: That's just declaring the delegate itself, you're not setting its value. [Check out this guide.](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Delegate Not Being Called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853482/swift-delegate-not-being-called)

Comment: Unrelated but this is Swift: No trailing semicolons!

Comment: But there's no problem on using them @vadian so when i'm back to ObjC or other languages I never forget them. Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when creating the headerview, set it's delegate to self.

```
headerView.delegate = self
```

You should add this after you initialized `headerView` in  `StoresFilterViewController`