# My delegate function is not being called in Swift

Tags: swift, delegates, delegation

I have a main view titled NoteTakerViewController. I have a weatherGetterController class with a protocol that returns 5 days of weather with a protocol function called getMyWeather. However the protocol function is not being called that returns the weather data to NoteTakerViewController. I am certain I have everything set up correctly with the delegates but perhaps I do not.

This is really not a duplicate of [Swift Delegate Not Being Called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853482/swift-delegate-not-being-called) as the solution on that page did not work.

Any help you could provide would be great.

Here's the relevant code snippets:

My weatherGetterController class:

```
protocol WeatherGetterControllerDelegate {
    func getMyWeather(weather: [FiveDayForecast])
}

class WeatherGetterController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var weatherGetterDelegate: WeatherGetterControllerDelegate?
```

And in the WeatherGetterController "getWeather" function call. The line

```
self.weatherGetterDelegate?.getMyWeather(weather: myForecast)
```

is not being called.

```
func getWeather() {
       ...
       getNetWeather { (fetchedInfo) in

            if let fetchedInfo2 = fetchedInfo {
                //self.updateUI(mainWeather: fetchedInfo2)
                //need to call delegate here
                let myForecast = self.figureFive(weather: fetchedInfo2)
                //return the forecast
                print(myForecast)
                self.weatherGetterDelegate?.getMyWeather(weather: myForecast)

            }

        }
```

Finally the function implementation in NoteTakerViewController:

```
class NoteTakerViewController: UIViewController, ..., UITextFieldDelegate, WeatherGetterControllerDelegate

    func getMyWeather(weather: [FiveDayForecast]) {

        print("get my weather")
        print(weather)

    }
```

Through debugging I can see that "weatherGetterDelegate" is set to nil and I don't know why.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the code where you assign a value to `weatherGetterDelegate`?

Comment: I don't have that and I think that's what I'm missing, any tips where to put it?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` could be a good place

Comment: What would I put in there, something to do with weatherGetterDelegate = self or something like that right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Delegate Not Being Called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853482/swift-delegate-not-being-called)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to make WeatherGetterController a property in NoteTakerViewController or a local variable where you call it but I will use the first option.

```
class NoteTakerViewController: UIViewController, ..., WeatherGetterControllerDelegate {
    var weatherGetterController: WeatherGetterController?

    //...

    func viewDidLoad() {
         //....
         weatherGetterController = WeatherGetterController()
         weatherGetterController?.delegate = self
    }

   //And then in some other part of your code you do
   func someFunc() {
       self.weatherGetterController?.getWeather()
```

I am curious why WeatherGetterController is define to be a viewcontroller, is that really correct?

```
class WeatherGetterController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
```

Personally I would remove that part

```
class WeatherGetterController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
```

Comment: That did it!!! Thanks Joakim! Also I did notice the UIViewController and removed it earlier but thanks for the catch! I'll mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in init of WeatherGetterController

```
  public weak var weatherGetterDelegate: WeatherGetterControllerDelegate?

  /* if you are not initializing it anywhere else 
  and if you are initializing it anywhere else then make sure you are 
  initializing WeatherGetterController there too and then put delegate   
  of WeatherGetterController to NoteTakerViewController object
   else write the below code */

  var model = NoteTakerViewController()

   public override init() {
      self. weatherGetterDelegate = model
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, however WeatherGetterController isn't a view, just a class so no ViewDidLoad is available (if I understand classes)

Comment: Awesome! That makes it more easy let me change my code

Comment: And tell me one thing where are you initializing the NoteTakerViewController?